# Having trouble with a linear lager question about kernel and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $2$-dimensional vector space, and let $\alpha={e_1,e_2} $ be a basis for $V$. Define a linear transformation $T: V\to V$ by declaring that:

$T(e_1+e_2)=2e_1−e_2 $

$T(e_2)=4e_1−2e_2$.

**a.** Find $[T]_{\alpha, \alpha}$. (one alpha is upper and the other lower!)

**b.** Find a basis for $\ker(T)$.

**c.** Find a new basis $\beta$ so that $[T]_{\beta, \alpha}$ is the row reduced echelon form of the matrix $[T]_{\alpha, \alpha}$.

I have got the first two parts. I am confused with the third part. What should I do next?

Comment: Mmmmm....lager.

Comment: What exactly is [T]αα? Is it the matrix of the linear Transformation with respect to the basis α? If it is then you might want to look at the matrix and with each step in manipulating it to RREF form you think about how the basis α would change to reflect the manipulation.

Comment: the RREF i got for the matrix is:                                 1 -2                                                          0 0                                                          what should i do with this on part c of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the matrix representation of $[T]_\alpha^\alpha = [T]_{\alpha,\alpha}$, you should have found:
$$
[T]_{\alpha,\alpha} = 
\pmatrix{
-2&4\\
1&-2
}
$$
For the second part, we row-reduce the augmented matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
-2&4&1&0\\
1&-2&0&1
} \to 
\pmatrix{
1&-2&0&1\\
0&0&1&2
}
$$
Our new basis $\beta$ will then be $\left\{\pmatrix{0\\1},\pmatrix{1\\2}\right\}$.